# Deedle: Setting header names when using SaveCsv

Tags: csv, f#, f#-data, deedle

I'm trying to use Deedle to save `.csv` files

```
type all_trades_schema = CsvProvider<"/trading/backtesting/strategy logs/all_trades.csv">

(new_trades |> Frame.ofRecords).SaveCsv(log_dirname+"/new_trades.csv")
```

the problem I have is that the original (template) file has column names, 
but the new file doesn't have any column names.

How can i fix my (little) problem ? thanks

(of note, my first column is `DateTime`, the others are float, but if this is important i'd like to know the right syntax when there are other types)

Comment: I've updated your question to more clearly indicate that you're using Deedle to save a CSV, not the Csv type provider.

Answer (score 4):

When you create Deedle frame from rows returned by the CSV provider using `Frame.ofRecords`, it unfortunately does not automatically get the column names, because the CSV provider represents those as a tuple - so the names are just `Item1`, `Item2` and so on, matching the property names of standard .NET tuple type.

To fix this, you can use `Frame.indexColsWith` which lets you replace the column names:

```
let headers = match csv.Headers with Some v -> v | _ -> failwith "No headers!"
let df = 
  csv.Rows 
  |> Frame.ofRecords
  |> Frame.indexColsWith headers

df.SaveCsv(log_dirname+"/new_trades.csv")
```

You can specify `keyNames` if you want to include the row keys - those are just ordinal numbers by default, in which case, you probably don't want to include them:

```
df.SaveCsv(log_dirname+"/new_trades.csv", includeRowKeys=false)
```

If you index your data so that e.g. the date is the index, then you can use:

```
df.SaveCsv(log_dirname+"/new_trades.csv", includeRowKeys=true,keyNames=["Date"])
```

Note that the name `keyNames` slightly misleadingly suggests that that you need to specify multiple names - this is only the case when you have multi-level indices, but that's somewhat odd and rarely used Deedle feature.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation, you have two options:

1. Pass `includeRowKeys=true` as a parameter to `SaveCsv`
2. Pass `keyNames=*keynames*` as a parameter to `SaveCsv`, where `*keynames*` is a list of header names

See http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/Deedle/features.html for the documentation.

To get the header names from the CsvProvider, you can do:
`all_trades_schema.GetSample().Headers`

This will give you a `string [] option`, so you will need to unwrap the DU like:

```fsharp
match all_trades_schema.GetSample().Headers with
| Some headers 
   -> (new_trades |> Frame.ofRecords).SaveCsv(log_dirname+"/new_trades.csv", keyNames = headers)
| None 
   -> (new_trades |> Frame.ofRecords).SaveCsv(log_dirname+"/new_trades.csv")
```